# Why the renormalization constant of the regularized $2D$ noise diverges as a logarithm

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, heat-equation, stochastic-differential-equations

**Motivation and overview**

I'm trying to understand the theory of regularity structures and in particular, following [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.03616) paper I'm looking to the $\Phi^4_d$ model on the $d$-dimensional torus $T^d$   i.e. the SPDE
$$
\partial_t \varphi(z)=\Delta \varphi(z) + \varphi^3(z) +\xi(z)
$$
where $z=(t,x_1,\cdots, x_d)$ and $\xi(z)$ is the space time white noise.

If we call $K(t,x)$ the heat kernel on the torus i.e.
$$
K(t,x):= \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\sum_{k \in 2\pi \mathbb{Z}^d}e^{-\frac{(x-k)^2}{t}}
$$
we can define
$$
Z(t,x):=\int_{} K(t-s,x-y) \xi(dz)
$$

We define $\rho_\delta$ the smooting kernel on scale $\delta$ i.e. a mollifiers such that
$$
|K * \rho_\delta| \lesssim \frac{1}{(\|z\|_s+\delta)^d} 
$$
where $\|z\|_s:=\sqrt{t}+\sum_{j=1}^d x_i$ is the scaled norm and $*$ is the space-time convolution.

We can (at least formally) define
$$
Z_\delta= Z * \rho_\delta
$$
At this point it is possible to calculate $Z_\delta^3$ as an iterated Ito integral and we have
$$
Z^3_\delta(y)= \int \prod_{j=1}^3 K* \rho_\delta(y-z_j) \xi(dz_1) \xi(dz_2) \xi(dz_3) + 3 \int  \left(\int (K* \rho_\delta(y-z) )^2 dz\right)K *\rho_\delta(y-z_1) \xi(dz_1)
$$
My doubt is about the second integral.

**My problem**

The second integral can be rewritten as $3 C_\delta Z_\delta$ where
$$
C_\delta= \int_{(0,s) \times T^d} (K* \rho_\delta)^2 dz
$$
In the linked paper it is stated that this constant, when the space dimension is $2$ and $\delta \to 0$ diverges logarithmically in delta. I don't understand how it is possible given the bound
$$
|K * \rho_\delta| \lesssim \frac{1}{(\|z\|_s+\delta)^2} 
$$
If instead $d=3$ the same integral should diverge as $\frac{1}{\delta}$.

**TL DR**

why is
$$
\lim_{\delta \to 0} \int_{(0,s) \times T^2} (K* \rho_\delta)^2  dz \approx \lim_{\delta \to 0} \log(\delta^{-1})
$$